Product Code vs. Product SKU
I'm trying to understand the differences between ProductCode and StockKeepingUnit and their use cases.
The documentation says:
Product Code

The internal code or product number that you use to identify the product.

Product SKU

The product’s SKU, which can be used with or in place of the Product Code field. For example, you can use the Product Code field to track the manufacturer’s identifying code, and assign the product a SKU when you resell it.

It seems the SKU was just added in Winter '18 (page 159), according to the release notes, and it says:

Keep track of the products that you offer with the new Product SKU field on products, which
can be used with or in place of the Product Code field. For example, you can track the
manufacturer’s identifying code in the Product Code field and assign the product a SKU when
you resell it. This change applies to both Lightning Experience and Salesforce Classic.


No two products can have the same SKU. The Product SKU field is searchable and can contain
up to 180 letters and numbers. It appears on default product page layouts for orgs created after
Winter ’18.

According to the bold sentence, the SKU is unique, leading to some odd behavior in unit tests.
So far I concluded the following:

Product Code is the main identifier for the product.
It is not unique.
Product SKU is an optional identifier for the product.
It is unique. In a weird way.

Is it possible to only use the SKU as the documentation suggests? Why is one unique while the other is not? Why this weird behavior in unit tests? And why have two fields to begin with?

That unit test issue is bizarre, and I think shouldn't happen in unit tests. But anyway, the answer on that question provides a workaround for that issue.
A product's code is generally a human-readable identifier for the product, whilst the SKU is a unique identifier for each product record, like an external ID. The SKU is primarily used for inventory and logistics management, but the code is more of an identifier or label for internal use in your organization.
To give you a Salesforcey example, if Ursa Major Solar sells solar panels and installations, their product catalog might include different solar panels, which might look like this:



Product Name
SKU
Code




Solar Panel (Small)
SLRP-S
PANEL


Solar Panel (Medium)
SLRP-M
PANEL


Solar Panel (Large)
SLRP-L
PANEL


Installation Service for Small Panels
SVC-INS-S
INSTALLATION


Installation Service for Medium Panels
SVC-INS-M
INSTALLATION


Installation Service for Large Panels
SVC-INS-L
INSTALLATION



Note how the code is used to identify the product, but not an attribute of it. It can also be used to somehow identify the items by category.
This is one way of using the SKU field and the code field. But, like the documentation says, you could use just the SKU too.

I'd say that SKU was added because it was unique (a desirable business feature) whereas ProductCode couldn;t be made unique, even with Duplicate Rules - one had to copy the ProductCode into a shadow field that was ExternalId - unique (a clunky workaround).
